# Miller Rabin Primality Test Error on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Im working on JavaScript to get three different algorithms to work in the same code, I set up a function for each algorithm. I'm trying to get three Primality testing methods: Trial Division, the Fermat Primality Test, and the Miller-Rabin Primality Test. The first two are working fine but the Miller-Rabin isn't. I'm pretty new to JavaScript and programming in general, so if you can find where I went wrong or can think of a way to make it work, please let me know! Thanks!

```js
// 1531 6389 68819 688889 6388819
// 68883889 688838831 1000000009
// 561 is a Carmichael number; a Fermat pseudoprime with the property a^n-1 = 1 mod n, for any "a" coprime to 561.
input = 5491763;
numTrials = 2000;

document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = input;

function TrialDiv(n) {

  if (n === 1) {
    return false;
  } else if (n === 2) {
    return true;
  } else {
    for (var x = 2; x < n; x++) {
      if (n % x === 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}

if ((TrialDiv(input)) === true) {
  a = "Prime"
} else if ((TrialDiv(input)) === false) {
  a = "Composite"
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
function gcd(x, y) {
  while (y !== 0) {
    var z = x % y;
    x = y;
    y = z;
  }
  return x;
}

function getRndInteger(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - 2)) + 2;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
function Fermat(n) {

  for (var t = 0; t = numTrials; t++) {
    m = getRndInteger(input);
    if (gcd(m, n) !== 1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return (Math.pow(m, n - 1) % n !== 1);
}

if ((Fermat(input)) === true) {
  b = "Prime";
} else if ((Fermat(input)) === false) {
  b = "Composite";
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
function genD(n) { // Generates "d" such that "n-1 = 2^s * d"
  var p = n - 1;
  var d = p / 2;
  while (d % 2 === 0) {
    d = d / 2;
  }
  return d;
}

function genS() { // Generates "s" such that "n-1 = 2^s * d"
  var s = Math.log2(p / d);
  return s;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
function MillerRabin(n) {

  for (var t = 0; t < numTrials; t++) {
    m = getRndInteger(input);
    if (gcd(m, n) !== 1) {
      return false;
    } else {
      for (var r = 0; r < genS(); r++) {
        power = (Math.pow(2, r) * genD(input));
        if (Math.pow(m, genD(input)) % n === 1 || Math.pow(m, power) % n === -1) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
    return true;
  }
}

if ((MillerRabin(input)) === true) {
  c = "Prime";
} else if ((MillerRabin(input)) === false) {
  c = "Composite";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("TrialDivision").innerHTML = a;  document.getElementById("FermatTest").innerHTML = b; document.getElementById("MillerRabinTest").innerHTML = c; '>Show</button>

  <hr>
  <b style="color:rgb(0,0,120)">PRIMALITY TESTS</b>
  <p></p>
  Input:
  <l id="input"></l>

  <hr>
  <h5 style="color:rgb(160,0,0)">TRIAL DIVISION</h5>
  <p></p>
  Output:
  <i id="TrialDivision"></i>

  <hr>
  <h5 style="color:rgb(160,0,0)">FERMAT PRIMALITY TEST</h5>
  <p></p>
  Output:
  <i id="FermatTest"></i>

  <hr>
  <h5 style="color:rgb(160,0,0)">MILLER-RABIN PRIMALITY TEST</h5>
  <p></p>
  Output:
  <i id="MillerRabinTest"></i>
</body>
<script>
```

That's how I wrote it up, this was purely created by me from the original mathematical algorithms for each test. What happens is that the Miller-Rabin Output doesn't show anything when the input number is prime; the algorithm isn't able to identify it. But it does identify composites correctly.

Please let me know of any improvements you think of!

Comment: What debugging have you done? Where do the errors come from?

Comment: What happens is the Miller-Rabin "Output" shows nothing when the input number is prime, but correctly identifies composites.

Comment: You should fix your indentation. You're probably missing a return statement in a branch somewhere. It's difficult to tell though when things are indented improperly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I just edited it and did the tidying up to show indentation better. I thought of the missing a return issue before and checked, but I couldn't think of where it could be missing.

Comment: When you say that it doesn't show anything, what *specifically* is the output of the `MillerRabin` function?

Comment: I get an `ReferenceError: p is not defined` from `s = Math.log2(p / d);` Since you don't declare any variables it looks like they are all global, which makes it kind of hard to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: The Output is literally nothing, I even separated the MillerRabin funciton into a different code to check its output.

Comment: @Mark_M How can I try to fix that? Should I declare every variable on the start?

Comment: @AgusPerezDelCastillo The output from a function can't be "literally nothing". Even if a function doesn't return anything, the return will still be `undefined`. I'm not asking what text is shown on the screen, I'm asking what the raw output from the function is.

Comment: I think you should declare any variable with meaningful names at the top. And use as few as you can. For example, in your `genD()` function you assign the variable `p`. It looks like a local variable, but you reference it in ` genS()`, which is were I'm seeing the error.

Comment: Just scanning through, your `Fermat()` function returns inside the `for` loop which means that look never goes past the first round.

Comment: @Carcigenicate When I input a composite number, the output is false (as it should), but when I input a prime number, it's undefined i guess. You can see here what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/AustinPerzben/h6o5kf1y/#&togetherjs=9yp5gRlLiO

Comment: Look at the console. When you put in a prime it is giving you the error I mentioned: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: p`

Comment: @Mark_M Thanks for that hint, if i declare "var p" in genD() I'll be able to fix that error right?

Comment: @Mark_M Also thanks for the Fermat() inside "for" thing, I'll fix that right away.

Comment: No it won't fix it because you reference it again in `genS()` if genS() is called before `genD()` it will throw an error.

Comment: Also look at the for loop in `MillerRabin`. Inside the loop you have an `if/else` and both return, so that loop also never runs past the first iteration.

Comment: Your fiddle is broken. Use `var` to make it clear where variables are being defined, actually *define* your variables in a way that doesn't allow for variables to be referenced before they're used, and fix your fiddle. Also, if you want to see what the raw value of something is, don't assign it to an element, since it won't show if it's an empty string, null, or undefined. Use `console.log`.

Comment: @Mark_M so how can I fix the variable p issue?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/AustinPerzben/yx6cuhuh/3/#&togetherjs=LCnhT2nR76@Carcigenicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some problems with loops not running. I'm not sure how the algorithm is supposed to work, so I don't if it's working or not, but the immediate problem is cause by leaky variable and variables not declared in functions (which makes them global).

The fix for this immediate problem is to declare the local variables in the functions so you don't depend on having them set by some other function.

```
function genD(n) { // Generates "d" such that "n-1 = 2^s * d"
    var p = n - 1;
    var d = p / 2;
    while (d % 2 === 0) {
        d = d / 2;
    }
    return d;
}

function genS(n) { // Generates "s" such that "n-1 = 2^s * d"
    var p = n - 1
    var d = p / 2
    var s = Math.log2(p / d);
    return s;
}
```

Once you start fixing the errors that crash there are a few other big problems. For example your `fermat()` potentially runs for ever:

```
for (var t = 0; t = numTrials; t++) {
```

Should be:

```
for (var t = 0; t == numTrials; t++) {
```

`=` sets `t` to `numTrails` for every loop

I think you should start at the beginning, put all your functions together and all you other logic code that calls the functions together so you can see what's going on.

Comment: Yes @AgusPerezDelCastillo - there are lots of other problems, see update.

Comment: So I changed the return true in MillerRabin to be outside the for loop, adn it worked. But when I did the same with Fermat, the whole thing made my browser crash...

Comment: Did you fix the `t == numTrials` in Fermat?

Comment: Oh i just saw the update, thanks a lot, sorry if I'm a bit slow, as I said in the post, i'm really new to the whole programming world.

Comment: I'm fixing that now.

Comment: So I did all the respective changes, I replaced the "t = numTrials" for "<="  in both Fermat and MillerRabin, checked all indentations, and amde sure the returns were correctly placed: It works just fine! Thanks a lot for the help, I'll upload the working version now.